# Send test message from one linux machine to another via command-line

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm new to Linux. I have two machines. I can successfully PING one machine from the other. I'm now trying to send some data from one machine to the other. The machine I'm sending to expects the content to come in on port 3000. I'm concerned the machine I'm sending from is blocking this, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way for me to test this via the command line in linux? If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, on the recieving host run:

```
sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 3000
```

to make sure you have a process running on that port.

then from the sending system, connect via telnet:

```
telnet <remoteIP> 3000
```

a text prompt should appear. if you are able to connect via telnet, then the port is accessible.

you can type the text of your command in there. what you type will depend on the kind of service running on port 3000 of the other box. if you enter the text correctly, telnet will display the remote systems response to your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the port availability with the telnet command.

Login to machine1 and type:

```
    telnet <machine2 IP Address> 3000
```

If the request connects successfully, then communication between those machines over that port is available. If the request times out, you might be dealing with a firewall issue.